# Flutter : JSON.parse fail on empty string

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to parse JSON data in Flutter and it is working fine. 
But when some data is empty or null then it is not working and giving error.

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetFollowing getFollowingFromJson(String str) => GetFollowing.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class GetFollowing {
    List<Content> content;
    int count;
    bool success;
    String error;

    GetFollowing({
        this.error,
        this.content,
        this.count,
        this.success,
    });

    factory GetFollowing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetFollowing(
        error: json["error"],
        content: List<Content>.from(json["content"].map((x) => Content.fromJson(x))),
        count: json["count"],
        success: json["success"],
    );

}

class Content {
    int uid;
    int following;
    String name;
    String profilePhoto;
    String baseLocation;
    String registrationDate;
    String country;

    Content({
        this.uid,
        this.following,
        this.name,
        this.profilePhoto,
        this.baseLocation,
        this.registrationDate,
        this.country,
    });

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        uid: json["uid"] ?? null,
        following: json["following"] ?? null,
        name: json["name"] ?? null,
        profilePhoto: json["profile_photo"] ?? null,
        baseLocation: json["base_location"] ?? null,
        registrationDate: json["registration_date"] ?? null,
        country: json["country"] ?? null,
    );

}
```

Here is the sample data.

1. Scenario

   {"error":"No record found.","success":false}
2. Scenario

```
{
    "content": [{
        "uid": 34,
        "following": 35,
        "name": "Sadi",
        "profile_photo": "noimage.png",
        "base_location": "New Delhi",
        "registration_date": "03-05-2020",
        "country": "India"
    }, {
        "uid": 34,
        "following": 37,
        "name": "Sameer",
        "profile_photo": "noimage.png",
        "base_location": "New Delhi",
        "registration_date": "03-05-2020",
        "country": "India"
    }, {
        "uid": 34,
        "following": 36,
        "name": "Simran",
        "profile_photo": "noimage.png",
        "base_location": "New Delhi",
        "registration_date": "03-05-2020",
        "country": "India"
    }],
    "count": 3,
    "success": true
}
```

I am getting error if content is null or empty then parse didn't complete and gives error.

```
Exception Caught: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content: (json["content"] as List).map((x as Map<String, dynamic>) => Content.fromJson(x)).toList()
```

Consider [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) or [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) to handle all your boiler plate for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do i need to place it exactly?

Comment: I placed your code and it is now giving different syntax error ---- The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'GetFollowing'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toList'.

Comment: It is still giving error. Tried calling: map<Content>(Closure: (dynamic) => Content)

Comment: i tried updated answer but it is giving syntax error on x and Map. Undefined class 'x'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'x'. Map ------ Expected to find ')'.